# Word replacing from text file to another line by line in python

Tags: python-2.7

```
f = open("info.txt",'r')
filedata = f.read()
f.close()

newdata = filedata.replace("opdut_decoded.wav","a88.wav")

f = open("info.txt",'w')
f.write(newdata)
f.close()
```

This is my example code to replace one word only.

I need to find a word from an text file and replace/rename that word from an another text file line by line by lookup words.

It's needs to be continue for multiple line rename. Is there is any way available in python.Can you Please guide me.

New Update:

1. I have a first text file with these lines sometext a8.ec3
   opdut_decoded , sometext a9.ec3 opdut_decoded , sometext a18.ec3
   opdut_decoded , sometext LFE1.ec3 opdut_decoded , sometext LFE7.ec3
   opdut_decoded , sometext LFE9.ec3 opdut_decoded , sometext a19.ec3
   opdut_decoded
2. And second text file have these lines.

   0a.ec3 , 1b.ec3 ,2c.ec3 ,3d.ec3 , 4e.ec3 , 5f.ec3 , 6e.ec3

Here i need to replace "-opdut_decoded.wav" with "0a.ec3",then second line of -opdut_decoded.wav" with "1b.ec3".similarly i need to replace all the lines in the text file.

**Updated Code:**

```
import re
with open("Rename_Changes_Details2.txt") as openfile:
 for line in openfile:
   for part in line.split():
       if "ec3" in part:
         print part
new_words = [part]  #This includes a new data in line by line  
infile = open('out_New.txt','r')    
data = infile.read()    
matches = re.findall(r'(opdut_decoded)',data)    
i = 0    
for m in matches:   
    data = re.sub(m,new_words[i],data,1)
    i += 1

out = open('out.txt','w')
out.write(data)
out.close()
```

**Input File:**

0a

1b

2c

3d

I have a text file with these below lines

1. -c0 -k2 -w1 -x1.0 -y1.0 -ia8.ac3 -opdut_decoded.wav
2. -c0 -k2 -w1 -x1.0 -y1.0 -ia9.ac3 -opdut_decoded.wav
3. -c0 -k2 -w1 -x1.0 -y1.0 -ia18.ac3 -opdut_decoded.wav
4. -c0 -k2  -w1 -x1.0 -y1.0 -iLFE1.ac3 -opdut_decoded.wav

I want to replace given input lines above by"-opdut_decoded.wav" in every line like this

1. -c0 -k2 -w1 -x1.0 -y1.0 -ia8.ac3 -0a.ac3
2. -c0 -k2 -w1 -x1.0 -y1.0 -ia9.ac3 -1b.ac3
3. -c0 -k2 -w1 -x1.0 -y1.0 -ia18.ac3 -2c.ac3
4. -c0 -k2  -w1 -x1.0 -y1.0 -iLFE1.ac3 -3d.ac3

Comment: can you give an example for input/output data?

Comment: For Example: I have a text file with lines of "xxxxxxxxxx opdut_decoded" .same word for all lines in that text file. And i have another text file with lines "example1" ,"example2" , "example3" like that in line by line. Here i need to find the word "opdut_decoded" in first text file and rename it to first line of a second text file accordingly.Similarly need to rename all the lines by using second text file lines.Here "xxxxxxxxx" means sone text in front of "opdut_decoded"

Comment: I share the details above as "New Update:"

Comment: does the below work for you? you can also read the list of replacements from a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this is how I would construct the list with your input file
import re    
    rep_file = open('in2','r')
    new_words = []
    for line in rep_file:
        line = line.strip()
        new_words.append(line + '.ec3')

    infile = open('in.txt','r')    
    data = infile.read()    
    matches = re.findall(r'(opdut_decoded\.wav)',data)    
    i = 0    
    for m in matches:   

        data = re.sub(m,new_words[i],data,1)
        i += 1

    out = open('out.txt','w')  
    out.write(data)    
    out.close()
```

Comment: line.strip() remove \n and other non visible characters

Comment: data = re.sub(m,new_words[i],data,1) - replace a single occurrence of m with the matching word in new_words

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
f  = open('info.txt', 'r+')
filedata = f.read().replace("opdut_decoded.wav", "a88.wav")
f.write(filedata)
f.close()
```

hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

```
    import re    
    new_words = ['0a.ec3' , '1b.ec3' ,'2c.ec3' ,'3d.ec3' , '4e.ec3' , '5f.ec3' , '6e.ec3']    
    infile = open('in.txt','r')    
    data = infile.read()    
    matches = re.findall(r'(opdut_decoded\.wav)',data)    
    i = 0    
    for m in matches:   

        data = re.sub(m,new_words[i],data,1)
        i += 1

 out = open('out.txt','w')  
 out.write(data)    
 out.close()
```

Comment: i think he needs this operation in same file

Comment: if so, either close the in file, reopen it for write  and dump data in, or open as rw, seek to the beginning and dump data it.

Comment: as I said, either define your list manually as i did ,or build your new_word list by reading from a file, your error means that your new_word list is sorter than the number of words to be replaced in the file.

Comment: Is this the file content you want replacements for? 
-c0 -k2 -w1 -x1.0 -y1.0 -ia8.ac3 -opdut_decoded.wav
-c0 -k2 -w1 -x1.0 -y1.0 -ia9.ac3 -opdut_decoded.wav
-c0 -k2 -w1 -x1.0 -y1.0 -ia18.ac3 -opdut_decoded.wav
-c0 -k2 -w1 -x1.0 -y1.0 -iLFE1.ac3 -opdut_decoded.wav

Comment: Yes..Need to replace "0a" in "opdut_decoded" like this.

Comment: Ok I saw your edit, my code works for me with your example.
Your code has a problem in constructing the list new_words, If you could supply the input file for constructing the list and logic got it, I will try to help

Comment: see above my code with list construction from your input

Comment: That only i shared  above as "Input File:"

Comment: I have more than 4000 list in one text file.If so i can't construct manually list as you given.

Comment: I updated the code with automatic list construction from file, please look